# WiFi card without host device

Tags: wifi, pcie

So to start I wasn't quite sure about where this question should be asked, so feel fre to relocate it if you want.

I'm setting up a system to notify me when a user enters an area. My plan is to use an old PCIE WiFi card powered from a small battery to detect when its within range. I want to know if a powered WiFi card needs to be initialized by the CPU or if a 5v power buss would be to have it show up in something like airodump-ng.

Thanks!

Comment: Firmware how exactly?

Comment: What do you mean? What firmware is the card? I dont know, but its atheros based.

Comment: The firmware is in storage on the host. It must be uploaded to the card in order for it to operate.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely it needs to be configured by a host CPU.  A WiFi card is a pretty dumb device - it's up to the host CPU to configure it in the right operational mode, often give it a MAC address, and of course to handle all the WEP/WPA and the entire 802.11 and TCP/IP stacks.

Comment: I understand that it needs setup to connect to a network, but what about just to broadcast its own Mac address?

Comment: A card doesn't broadcast anything. The OS requests a  connection with an access point. You can not do a single thing without a host OS to drive the card.